# My macbook doesn't turn on by attempting lot of times

Tags: hardware

I am having a issue with my Macbook where it doesn't turn on (power-on) randomly, And turns on randomly by attempting lot of times to open it, what issues could I be possibly be facing? My laptop is heating up but but no signs of turning on.

Comment: How old is it? TBH, it sounds like a hardware problem -- either the power management on the logic board, or the battery. Take it to an Apple Store, or other authorised Apple repair shop (or any local repair shop that says they'll do Macs) -- in that order!

Comment: When it does power on, you might try [Apple Diagnostics](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731) to see what information is returned.

Comment: Please edit this once you’ve followed https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204267

Answer (score 1):

You can try resetting the SMC

[How to reset the SMC of your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295)

or running diagnostics

[Use Apple Diagnostics to test your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731)

Barring that as others have suggested this probably requires hardware support.